# How to remove duplicate strings from list

Tags: python, list, function, duplicates

Say I have a function

parameter 1 - a list of strings, each string element is a friend's email
parameter 2 - a string, a friend's email you'd should to add to the list or if empty, do not add (just clean the list and remove repeats)

def email_list(previous_emails, new_email):

and this list of emails is used
['media@gmail.com', 'carpool@gmail.com', 'marcopolo@gmail.com', 'MEDIA@gmail.com']
but it just prints this list again instead of just the first 3 emails.

I tried to use different methods i found on here but nothing is really getting rid of the duplicates, it just keeps printing the orginal list.

Comment: There are no duplicate strings in the list you have shown. Upper-case and lower-case versions are different strings.

Comment: You need to [lower the case of the characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

Comment: @Rojo `.casefold` might be better than `.lower`, although, I don't actually know what would be appropriate for emails. In any case, `.lower` is probably find for this exercise.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `casefold` would too aggressive for an email since 'ß' is not equivalent to "ss" in a URL (I highly doubt ß would ever appear in an email/URL, but still).

Comment: @Rojo yes, although, I do know that, for example, `.` are ignored in email addresses, but I think this is just a practice exercise

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def email_list(previous_emails, new_email):
  previous_emails.extend(new_email)
  return list(set(previous_emails))
email_list(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'b'])
```